# How to draw box plots for each cluster in same diagram?

Tags: r, data-analysis, rattle

I have done the clustering using Rattle and at the end I have the following format of data:
[image]

I need to draw the boxplot for each cluster in the same diagram. (i.e there are 5 clusters. So, in X axis, I need 1 to 5 cluster numbers and in Y axis I need age.)

I did the following things. But I couldn't get as I expect.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anybody suggest correct settings to get 5 box plots in parallel for each cluster?

Comment: I don't know about Rattle, but in the console you can use a formula like this: `foo <- data.frame(Age=rnorm(100),Cluster=sample(LETTERS[1:5],100,replace=TRUE))`, then the boxplot: `boxplot(Age~Cluster,foo)`

Comment: I have found the reason. The cluster variable should be in the format of "Category"

Answer (score 0):

In  R u  can make it. first  read the  file in frame.
reviews <- read.csv ("abc.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

boxplot(reviews$age ~ reviews$Cluster)